# How to save “text/pdf” PDF files on the disk from an incoming mail in Mutt

Tags: mutt, mime-types

I receive emails with PDF attachments that have the MIME type "text/pdf". This is obviously not good, but some mail clients are doing that...

The problem is that saving such an attachment in Mutt leads to a file on the disk that cannot be opened by a PDF viewer. The file size is indeed different by a few bytes from what it should be.

How can I save such attachments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never come across a PDF as text/pdf, but presumably Mutt is trying to do a line ending conversion (e.g., CRLF → LF).

Easiest way to stop it would seem to be to (in the Attachments screen) edit the MIME type. By default, that's bound to <kbd>^E</kbd>. Then save it.

(untested, as I've never seen a `text/pdf` PDF attachment.)

Answer (score 0):

I use `pdftotext` to render PDFs in `mutt`.

In your `~/.mutt/muttrc` define a `~/.mutt/mailcap` path:

```
# define mailcaps
set mailcap_path=~/.mutt/mailcap:/etc/mailcap
set mailcap_sanitize
```

In your `~/.mutt/mailcap`:

```
text/pdf; pdftotext %s -; copiousoutput; needsterminal; description="Adobe PDF Doc"
```

Comment: Normally the mailcap would have "application/pdf" as the mime type, but I used text/pdf in my example.  May want to add both.